# How to publish a web site running in a docker container on production?

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, port

I have a web application running in a docker container on production server. Now I need to make API requests to this application. So, I have two possibilities:
1) Link a domain
2) Make requests directly by IP

I'm using a cloud server for that. In my previous experience I linked the domain to a folder. But now I don't know how to link the domain to a  running container on ip_addr:port.

I found this link 
https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/datacenter/ucp/2.2/guides/user/services/use-domain-names-to-access-services/
but it's for docker enterprice. Using of that is impossible for the moment.

Comment: Could you give us more details of the deployment so we can better assist you?
Running `docker inspect <containerID>` would help us a ton. 
Also, is this a production server that you own? Is it on a VM in the cloud? 
Do you know the networking layers between the server that your container runs on to the public internet?
In order to refer to your container by domain name, you would set up an A record to point to the IP address of the server your container is one. In order to better help you, we would have to know who your domain name service provider is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose a docker application to the public without using compose or other orchestration tools like Kubernetes, you can use the `docker run -p hostPort:containerPort` option to expose your container port. Make sure your application is listening on `0.0.0.0:[container port]` inside your container. To access the service externally, you would use the host's IP, and the port that the container port has been mapped to.

See more [here](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/docker-networking-rules/)

If you want to link to a domain, you can update your DNS records to point your domain to your host IP address.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use kubernetes because it will ease many operations. But `docker-compose` can also be used.

If you want to simply deploy using `docker` it can be done by mapping hostPort to containerPort.